# GWT throws URIError repeatedly

Tags: java, gwt

Test case:

1.Open valid application url, for example

http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/hosted/index?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#xxx:yyy

2.Change url to have some UTF-8 encoded characters, for example,

http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/hosted/index?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#xxx:%u0041

As you see, it contains invalid character %u0041.
After that, GWT is throwing infinite exceptions with stacktrace

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (URIError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(10822), JavaScript object(10823), JavaScript object(11420)]): The URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:356)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor299.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why it throws repeated exceptions and how can I avoid it?

**EDIT**
Unfortunately I cannot show code since it seems to me that it is GWT's internal stuff. I don't code it, when I change URL in URL bar and press enter, GWT reacts all by itself. It is not feasible option, but it fails penetration tests.

**EDIT 2**
It appears it happens only in IE 11 
GWT version - 2.6.1

Comment: Can we see the actual code you're using that produces the error? The example URL with `%u0041` is invalid because that's not the right format for URL %-escaping.

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: If this is GWT internal code, maybe we can reproduce it without your custom app. Does it happen when you put a bogus %-encoded character in the URL for the "Hello world" sample app in the GWT distribution?

Comment: Unfortulately it does not. It does not even complain about wrong url encoding